Does Chabad have a specific response to Breslov about studying Philosophy books?
Chayei Moharan 407-408 brings that Rebbe Nacham forbade studying philosophy works, such as Moreh Nevuchim, Chovot Levavot Gate of Unity, Sefer HaIkkarim, and even sections of Mishneh Torah such as Yesodei HaTorah and Hilchot Deot.
The Alter Rebbe gave a general warning about these works in Hilchot Talmud Torah 3:7, but given that Chabad generally do learn Mishneh Torah, and the Rebbe quotes these works often and tries to integrate them, I wonder if Chabad have ever given a direct response to Rebbe Nachman and explained why they disagree, or how their practices in this regard are ok etc.
(thanks @Yehuda for inspiring this question)

In Chayei Moharan 132 it records that Rebbe Nachman disagreed conclusively with the Alter Rebbe on a number of issues - I've never been able to get any clarification on what they disagreed on, and I wonder if this is one of the topics ;)

Not that I've ever heard of though think there is an agreement about not learning more nevuchim

@Dude the Rebbe quotes Moreh Nevuchim a LOT

Not to weigh in, but my Rosh Yeshiva R' Yaakov Weinberg z"l was said to have believed that learning many of these examples is unhelpful today, because they are busy with issues that no longer concern us. No one cares any more about Aristotle's system. ON THE OTHER HAND, they all contain incredible insights in all kinds of other ways, like any sefer by a Rishon. That may be similar to what the Shulchan Aruch Harav said.

@MichoelR the intro to the beit Yaacov explains that Rambam was using the Moreh to teach Kabbalah in a very "dressed up" way because it was forbidden to do so at the time, but now it is not and there are proper ways of learning Kabbalah so that's why it is forbidden. Nevertheless this is not relevant to my question

The fact that the Rebbe quotes Moreh Nevuchim doesn't mean that he disagrees with Rebbe Nachman - it could just be that he is quoting parts that are okay for everyone to know.

@User123 that logic is sound but doesn't apply to Mishneh Torah

Do chassidic groups generally respond to one another's rulings?

I believe I remember seeing somewhere that Chabad's argument is that every Jew is obligated to learn the entire Torah - including Ma'aseh Merkava etc. which is explained in short in Mishnah Torah - just not to learn it in deapth, which is the issue with Moreh Nevuchim.

@יהושעק see the first comment. It does happen

@User123 if you find the source I can ask why Chabad disagrees with Ishbitz next :)

I am very surprised at the idea that a later authority such as Rabbi Nachman of Breslov or the Gaon Rabbi Shneur Zalman would take upon himself to forbid Klal Yisroel to learn the works of leading Rishonim.  I do note that the relevant portion of Hilchos Talmud Torah of Shulchan Aruch Harav does not mention by name which books of earlier authorities he prefers that people not read.

@YehoshuaKahan yes very surprising +1. Ever seen this Beur HaGra? And yes, well noted.

@RabbiKaii
Yes, I have seen the comment of the Gra, though I appreciate your bringing it up.  I think it's interesting that while he disagrees with Rambam, and quite vigorously, nothing in his words (at least, in this particular comment) says or even suggests that one should not study the Rambam, or any part of the Rambam.

I don't see where SA Harav says not read any legitimate Torah book. He just says to be cautious about sections referencing heretical works.

But as a general rule, Chabad does avoid studying classical Jewish philosophy: https://toratchabad.com/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%91%D7%93

@YehoshuaKahan Rebbe Nachman mentions the Moreh Nevuchim in Chayei Moharan 408. I've seen the Leshem Shevo V'achlamah say something similar in Chelek rishon Drushei Olam Hatohu Drush 5 Siman 8 (although it has been some time since I've seen that source so I don't recall if he mentions the Moreh Nevuchim directly or just discusses the issue of learning chakirah bichlal and the issues of the Rambam having done so).

Interesting.  Thank you, @Yehuda

@YehoshuaKahan I don’t think it’s a ban on reading those books it’s more like an advisement that most people aren’t ready for them. Like you would advise a 5 year old not to try learning gemara.

@mroll I disagree.  Looking at his wording, he says that it is forbidden to read the words of non-Jewish philosophers, because their ideas are full of apikorsus.  He continues to say that one "needs to be careful" of them even when their words are discussed sifrei Yisroel.  He then quotes Chazal saying that one who reads "sefarim chitzonim" has no portion in the World to Come.

@mroll   He finally writes that chachmei Yisroel of earlier generations had to deal with such ideas in order to rebut them and win back the minds of Klal Yisroel, that had been influenced by their ideas.  But this no longer applies today. So it's "assur," "must be careful," "have no portion in the World to Come," and "earlier generations faced a situation that does not exist today."  That sounds pretty decisive to me.
